# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid - Add new row not inserting

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page on my app that allows the user to create (insert) a new row on my table:

```
Employee   Manager    id    Status
john       ryan       1     Active
angela     ryan       2     Active
steve      jim        3     Inactive
```

Id column acting as primary key.
My Interactive Grid is working ok for updates, the 'add row' button works (a new row is displayed and info can be added into it). But when clicking on save, this 'new row added' disappears, info doesn't get inserted into the table at all.
My query as follows:

```
select
--PK
id,
Manager,
Employee,
--Update only available when Status is active:
decode(Status,'Active', 'U',
                    'X') as Editable
from my_table

IG attributes:
Edit = enabled
Allowed Operations = update row, add row
Allowed Row Operations Column = Editable
Lost Update Type = row value
Add row if empty = Yes
```

Anybody has any idea why?

Thank you all

Comment: Any errors in the console when that happens ? What about that "editable" column - how are you expecting that to work ? Maybe remove that column from the query just for testing and seeing if that makes a difference ?

Comment: Hi, thank you. It doesn't make a difference really, fully removed the decode part and still doesn't save the insert. 
As for the errors, I get none, a new row shows up, but when I click on save it disappears.
Any other ideas would be truly appreciated

Comment: Where is your primary key column in the query ? You do need that in there (can be hidden or display only)

Comment: My bad, forgot to include it. Edited the answer to show it up.
I have it on my query as a hidden column (PK = Yes for this column).

Comment: Have no clue - it's hard to debug with this little info and I'm no IG expert. I'd rebuild the region from scratch if that is an option.

Comment: thank you, appreciate the help.
Created a new page with a new IG (not a copy) and got the same result. Not sure if the issue lies on the sequence populating the Id column 'not matching with the IG auto process'...will keep trying. Thanks!

Comment: If you can reproduce this on a workspace in apex.oracle.com (create one specially for this issue and give me access) I'm happy to have a look.

Comment: Hopefully you've solved this problem by now?

For others in your situation, you mentioned a sequence. How would you expect that to get set on Insert? Do you have a trigger or is the id column defined as "number generated by default on null as identity"?
Otherwise I'd expect the Insert to fail.